# How do I get Solr http request api through Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, solr

I am building a Solr-based application using Node JS and I build this query using a Node JS package solr-client. How do I get the HTTP request API like in the picture below through Node JS?
[image]

Everytime I try to use request package, it only returns me the body of the json, not the url itself.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the 'request' object returned from the `.search` method? From what I can get from the source of `request.js`, there's a property named `uri` which should contain the URI of the current request.

Comment: I don't seem to get what you mean, sorry. Whose search method? There is no search method in request that I know of. I tried looking for uri in request documentation and it is apparently a parameter sent to the request, not something returned. Sorry again that I don't understand, my english is a little bit limited.

Comment: If you're using `solr-client`, you use a method like `.search` to call the search you've highlighted above. The method returns a 'request' object as far as I can see, where one of the properties is 'uri' (on the object as well). I don't have a node test environment here, so you'll have to test it yourself (access the .uri property directly, inspect the request object in a debugger or iterate over it yourself).